# How to Toast all items in recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to toast all items in recycler view. Basically I have created one arraylist named as courseModelArraylist . and i want to toast all items that resent in this arraylist.
Can we listview instead of recycler view ?
I tried in onBindViewHolder but it only toast newly added item. I want all items to be Toast.

below is my code:-

```
package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class CourseRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CourseRVAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    // variable for our array list and context
    private ArrayList<CourseModal> courseModalArrayList;
    private Context context;
    public static String result;
    // constructor
    public CourseRVAdapter(ArrayList<CourseModal> courseModalArrayList, Context context) {
        this.courseModalArrayList = courseModalArrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // on below line we are inflating our layout
        // file for our recycler view items.

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.course_rv_item, parent, false);
         return new ViewHolder(view);
         



    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // on below line we are setting data
        // to our views of recycler view item.

            CourseModal modal = courseModalArrayList.get(position);
            holder.courseNameTV.setText(modal.getCourseName());


    }

    public static String getvalue(){
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // returning the size of our array list
        return courseModalArrayList.size();
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // creating variables for our text views.
        private TextView courseNameTV;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // initializing our text views

            courseNameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVCourseName);


        }}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your adapter to toast all the items in courseModalArrayList like below

```
public void toastAll()
{
    for(CourseModal courseModal:courseModalArrayList )
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, courseModal.getWhatEver(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

call this method whenever needed.

Comment: I tried but do not getting the result. can you please add this in my code